# How to install node modules in a temp folder in azure

Tags: npm, azure-devops, npm-install, node-modules

I am trying to set up a build in Azure and one of the steps I want to implement is installing my production node modules in a tmp directory. I have added this in my `azure-pipelines.yml` file

```
- script: | 
mkdir ./tmp
npm install --production --prefix ./tmp
displayName: 'npm install --production'
```

I want this to create a temp directory then install my packages inside that directory. When I do that I get this error

`no such file or directory, rename '/home/vsts/work/1/s/tmp/lib/node_modules/...' -> '/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/...'`

What is happening here? Seems like a pretty straightforward process

Comment: what agent you are using ?

Comment: using Ubuntu 16.04